# Modern UI file picker not displaying

Tags: windows-8, file-management, modern-ui

I have a problem with modern UI apps. After investigating a bit, I narrowed it down to the file picker not appearing. This results in a number of problems, as:

- unable to open file in Music app
- unable to change lock screen background
- unable to browse through files&folders using third party
  modern UI apps

and possibly others I have yet to discover.

What I've tried already:

- removing third parties from startup and services
- cleaning registry with a software suggested from a Microsoft MVP (can't recall wich sw it was, but I can find it if necessary)
- using the dedicated app troubleshooter (no results, only suggested to update graphics drivers which were already up to date)
- running sfc /scannow (found and fixed problems, but didn't manage to solve my issue)
- running chkdsk /f on the system drive (found nothing)

I've been suggested to make system refresh / wipe and clean install. I utterly refuse to go through the hurdle of reinstalling all of my software just for this, but any other nondestructive solution is really really (really) welcome.

Comment: Sometimes the file picker pops up after 5 or 6 seconds. How much time did you wait?

Comment: Sometimes, as in my case, it never does.. or it crashes the app trying to display it, which also happens to some apps but I forgot to mention.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you restart after `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: Yes, many times since then